# Play ws scala server hangs up on request after 120seconds - which options to use?

Tags: scala, web-services, playframework

I am pretty sure that this is a config problem, so I'll post my code and the relevant application.conf options of my play app.

I have a play server that needs to interact with another server "B" (basically multi-file upload to B). The interaction happens inside an async -Action which should result in an OK with B's response on the upload. This is the reduced code:

```
def authenticateAndUpload( url: String) = Action.async( parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    val form = authForm.bindFromRequest.get
    val (user, pass) = (form.user, form.pass)
    //the whole following interaction with the other server happens in a future, i.e. login returns a Future[Option[WSCookie]] which is then used
    login(user, pass, url).flatMap {
      case Some(cookie) => //use the cookie to upload the files and collect the result, i.e. server responses
        //this may take a few minutes and happens in yet another future, which eventually produces the result
      result.map(cc => Ok(s"The server under url $url responded with $cc"))
      case None =>
        Future.successful(Forbidden(s"Unable to log into $url, please go back and try again with other credentials."))
    }
  }
```

I am pretty sure that the code itself works since I can see my server log which nicely prints B's responses every few seconds and proceeds until everything is correctly uploaded. The only problem is that the browser hangs up with a server overloaded message after 120s which should be a play default value - **but for which config parameter?**

I tried to get rid of it by setting every play.server.http. timeout option I could get my hands on and even decided to use play.ws, specific akka, and other options of which I am quite sure that they are not necessary... however the problem remains, here is my current application.config part:

```
ws.timeout.idle="3600s"
ws.timeout.request ="3600s"
ws.timeout.response="3600s"

play.ws.timeout.idle="3600s"
play.ws.timeout.request="3600s"  
play.ws.timeout.response="3600s"

play.server.http.connectionTimeout="3600s"
play.server.http.idleTimeout="3600s"
play.server.http.requestTimeout="3600s"
play.server.http.responseTimeout="3600s"
play.server.http.keepAlive="true"

akka.http.host-connection-pool.idle-timeout="3600s"
akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.idle-timeout= "3600s"
```

The browser hang up happened both on Safari and Chrome, where Chrome additionally started a second communication with B after about 120 seconds - also both of these communications succeeded and produced the expected logs, only the browsers had both hang up.

I am using Scala 2.12.2 with play 2.6.2 in an SBT environment, the server is under development, pre-compiled but then started via run - I read that it may not pick up the application.conf options - but it did on some file size customizing. Can someone tell me the correct config options or my mistake on the run process?